# How to fix a crack in a silicone grip

Tags: repair, handlebars, mechanical, crack, grips

I have a brand new pair of silicone grips. Somehow, one of the grips got a crack. Its mostly an aesthetic issue, as no fragments of the grip where lost.

Is there any glue appropriate for silicone to fix the crack?

Comment: If they're brand new, the first thing you should try to do is get a replacement from wherever you bought them.

Comment: Hardly anything sticks to silicone.

Comment: You could try Shoe Goo. It is pretty flexible when dry and is strong enough to reglue shoe soles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your only options are to replace them with a non cracked set, or to cover the crack with something else.

Silicon does not glue very well.

Personally I have used a 10cm section of 30mm heatshrink tubing, and used a hot air blower to contract the tube down on itself.  This makes a grippy top-skin for a handgrip that was breaking down and going tacky.

Downsides, most heatshrink is black and often has lines of text printed on it.  Some variants have glue on the inside, which helps too.

Comment: I'll inject here that my favorite material for covering grips is "hockey tape".  It's the tape that is used on the handles of hockey sticks and is quite strong and durable.  And it's intended to be a "grip".